# searchbar textDidChange error

Tags: swift, uitableview, search, filter, uisearchbar

I am trying to implement a searchbar for a tableView and I am receiving the error "...Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Place' and 'String'" in my textDidChange method. The tableView is populated from a Firebase database "placeList" array. Not sure where the error source is coming from. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
lazy var searchBar:UISearchBar = UISearchBar()

var placeList = [Place]()
var placesDictionary = [String: Place]()

var isSearching = false
var filteredData = [Place]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle.prominent
    searchBar.placeholder = " Search Places..."
    searchBar.sizeToFit()
    searchBar.isTranslucent = false
    searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    navigationItem.titleView = searchBar

    tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellId)

    if isSearching {
        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredData[indexPath.row].place
    } else {

    cell.textLabel?.text = placeList[indexPath.row].place

    }
    return cell
}
```

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

```
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        isSearching = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        isSearching = true
        // error in below line of code...
        filteredData = placeList.filter({$0.place == searchBar.text})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property `placeList` is an array of `Place` objects. When you call the `filter` function on your array (`placeList.filter({$0 == searchBar.text!})`), what you are saying is "filter placeList where a Place object is equal to searchBar.text". A place object is not a `String`, you cannot compare two different types. I'm not familiar with your data model, or your `Place` class, but maybe you have some type of String property in your `Place` class which you could use to compare? For instance, say `Place` had a property called `id` of type String, you could then filter through comparison like so: `filteredData = placeList.filter({$0.id == searchBar.text!})` - notice the added `$0.id`.

You can only compare a String to a String

Comment: Thanks that makes sense...I do have an Model "Place" NSObject with String Value "place", and my firebase data model has a child value titled "place" as well. So I updated filteredData = placeList.filter({$0.place == searchBar.text}) but still no luck...? It does not crash or give me an error when I run the application - but does not return filtered results on searchBar textChange input.

Comment: @user3708224 - so the way that code is written, it will only filter Place objects where the `place` string is exactly equal to your `searchBar.text`. you might try making both strings lowercase to avoid any kind of case-sensitive issues. You could try this: `placeList.filter({$0.place.lowercased() == searchBar.text.lowercased()})`. If that still doesn't work then it would lead me to believe that none of your `Place` objects in Firebase have a `place` string that's equal to your search text.

Comment: @user3708224- Also if you're trying to just filter for `place` strings that only contain the text in your search (but not exactly equal to), you can use the `contains` function for Swift's String API - that would look something like this: `placeList.filter({$0.place.lowercased().contains(searchBar.text.lowercased())})`